# How can I update a map inside a map?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a `Map of Maps` that looks like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> data;
```

I want to update the inner map.

Should I do the following everytime I want to update the innermap or is there any other direct/better way of accomplishing it?

```
Map<String, Object> innerMap = data.get("outer_key");
innerMap.put("inner_key", value);
data.put("outer_key", innerMap);
```

Comment: `inner.put("inner_key", value);`, should that have been `innerMap.put("inner_key", value);`?

Comment: You don't need the third line.  You're sharing a reference to a single instance (the inner map).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may have a typo in there and I'm assuming `inner` is actually `innerMap`. I would probably change it a bit to account for `null` values in the outer map:

```
Map<String, Object> innerMap = data.get("outer_key");

// Added this if statement to handle null values in the outer map.
if (innerMap == null) {
    innerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("outer_key", innerMap);
}

innerMap.put("inner_key", value);
// data.put("outer_key", innerMap); <-- This is not needed, innerMap is already a value in
                                     // the outer map.
```

Comment: Thanks, The "<-- This is not needed ..." part helps!!

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using the google guava library, which has a Table class (basically map of maps):

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html

Then you have available a put method that takes row, column, and value (which is a bit simpler).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Good to know about the guava library.